# Flows and ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let r''=1. Convert to 1st order system & find the flow and verify $\phi_t o \phi_s = \phi_{t+s}$

I wrote it as:

$r'=u$

$u'=1$

And solved to get

$r(t)=ut+r_0$

$u=t+u_0$

So, the flow is $(ut + r_0, t + u_0)$

I can't seem to verify the final part. Can you show me where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should have:
$$
u(t) = t + u_0
$$
and
$$
r(t)=\int_0^t \bigg( \tau + u_0 \bigg) d\tau
$$
$$
r(t)=r_0 + u_0 t + \frac{t^2}{2}
$$
so your flow is 
$$
\phi(t,r_0,u_0) =\bigg(r_0 + u_0 t + \frac{t^2}{2} \ ,\  t + u_0\bigg)
$$